# React-query cache doesn't persist on page refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I would like to set a 24 hours cache once a `useQuery` request has succeeded.

But as soon as I refresh the page, the cache is gone. I see it because I console.log a message each time the route is hit on my server.

How to prevent this behaviour and implement a real cache?

Here is the code:

```js
   import { useQuery } from "react-query";
import { api } from "./config";

const _getUser = async () => {
  try {
const res = api.get("/get-user");
return res;
  } catch (err) {
return err;
  }
};

export const getUser = () => {
  const { data } = useQuery("contact", () => _getUser(), {
cacheTime: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24,
  });
  return { user: data && data.data };
};


// then in the component:
  const { user } = getUser();

return (
<div >
  hello {user?.name}
</div>
```

I've also tried to replace `cacheTime` by `staleTime`.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

if you reload the browser, the cache is gone because the cache lives in-memory. If you want a persistent cache, you can try out the (experimental) persistQueryClient plugin: https://react-query.tanstack.com/plugins/persistQueryClient

Comment: Cool, but from what I've read, it's basically only a local storage item. So it's not secure at all. Is there another way to make the cache persist in a secure manner?

Comment: Where would you want to store it?

Comment: Anywhere secure. At the moment, I make an api call when the app mounts to retrieve the user informations. It contains sensitive information such as geolocation data, etc. On a search result page, a user can open a result in a new tab when he clicks on it. So if he opens 20 tabs in two minutes, it makes a lot of charge on the server. Yes, I could use Reddis on the server and cache the data, but it cost more money on Heroku. So I was hoping to find a solution with React-query. I'm actually fine with page refresh, I'm more worried about making a new call on each new tab.

Comment: No storage is secure on the frontend - you can encrypt the data with Crypto API. What you are looking for sounds like the broadcast plugin to transmit data between tabs: https://react-query.tanstack.com/plugins/broadcastQueryClient

Comment: This feature seems awesome! It crashes for the moment, so I've opened an issue on react-query's github. But it looks very promising! Thanks!

Comment: @DoneDeal0 - if you don't want your data to NOT BE easily readable in `localStorage`, you'll need to define your own custom serializer and deserializer functions. This feature is still experimental, checkout the docs and search for the localStorage persistence

Answer (score 0):

React query has now an experimental feature for persisting stuff on localStorage.
Nonetheless, I preferred using a custom hook, to make useQuery more robust and to persist stuff in localSTorage.
Here is my custom hook:

```html
import { isSameDay } from "date-fns";
import { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { useBeforeunload } from "react-beforeunload";
import { useQuery, useQueryClient } from "react-query";

import { store as reduxStore } from "../../redux/store/store";

const LOCAL_STORAGE_CACHE_EXPIRY_TIME = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 23; // 23h
const divider = "---$---";
const defaultOptions = {
    persist: true, // set to false not to cache stuff in localStorage
    useLocation: true, // this will add the current location pathname to the component, to make the query keys more specific. disable if the same component is used on different pages and needs the same data
    persistFor: LOCAL_STORAGE_CACHE_EXPIRY_TIME,
    invalidateAfterMidnight: false, // probably you want this to be true for charts where the dates are visible. will overwrite persistFor, setting expiry time to today midnight
    defaultTo: {},
};

const getLocalStorageCache = (dataId, invalidateAfterMidnight) => {
    const data = localStorage.getItem(dataId);
    if (!data) {
        return;
    }
    try {
        const parsedData = JSON.parse(data);
        const today = new Date();
        const expiryDate = new Date(Number(parsedData.expiryTime));
        const expired =
            today.getTime() - LOCAL_STORAGE_CACHE_EXPIRY_TIME >= expiryDate.getTime() ||
            (invalidateAfterMidnight && !isSameDay(today, expiryDate));

        if (expired || !parsedData?.data) {
            // don't bother removing the item from localStorage, since it will be saved again with the new expiry time and date when the component is unmounted or the user leaves the page
            return;
        }

        return parsedData.data;
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(`unable to parse local storage cache for ${dataId}`);
        return undefined;
    }
};

const saveToLocalStorage = (data, dataId) => {
    try {
        const wrapper = JSON.stringify({
            expiryTime: new Date().getTime() + LOCAL_STORAGE_CACHE_EXPIRY_TIME,
            data,
        });
        localStorage.setItem(dataId, wrapper);
    } catch (e) {
        console.log(
            `Unable to save data in localStorage for ${dataId}. Most probably there is a function in the payload, and JSON.stringify failed`,
            data,
            e
        );
    }
};

const clearOtherCustomersData = globalCustomerId => {
    // if we have data for other customers, delete it
    Object.keys(localStorage).forEach(key => {
        if (!key.includes(`preferences${divider}`)) {
            const customerIdFromCacheKey = key.split(divider)[1];
            if (customerIdFromCacheKey && customerIdFromCacheKey !== String(globalCustomerId)) {
                localStorage.removeItem(key);
            }
        }
    });
};

const customUseQuery = (queryKeys, getData, queryOptions) => {
    const options = { ...defaultOptions, ...queryOptions };
    const store = reduxStore.getState();
    const globalCustomerId = options.withRealCustomerId
        ? store.userDetails?.userDetails?.customerId
        : store.globalCustomerId.id;
    const queryClient = useQueryClient();
    const queryKey = Array.isArray(queryKeys)
        ? [...queryKeys, globalCustomerId]
        : [queryKeys, globalCustomerId];
    if (options.useLocation) {
        if (typeof queryKey[0] === "string") {
            queryKey[0] = `${queryKey[0]}--path--${window.location.pathname}`;
        } else {
            try {
                queryKey[0] = `${JSON.stringify(queryKey[0])}${window.location.pathname}`;
            } catch (e) {
                console.error(
                    "Unable to make query. Make sure you provide a string or array with first item string to useQuery",
                    e,
                );
            }
        }
    }
    const queryId = `${queryKey.slice(0, queryKey.length - 1).join()}${divider}${globalCustomerId}`;

    const placeholderData = useRef(
        options.persist
            ? getLocalStorageCache(queryId, options.invalidateAfterMidnight) ||
                  options.placeholderData
            : options.placeholderData,
    );
    const useCallback = useRef(false);
    const afterInvalidationCallback = useRef(null);
    const showRefetch = useRef(false);
    const onSuccess = freshData => {
        placeholderData.current = undefined;
        showRefetch.current = false;
        if (options.onSuccess) {
            options.onSuccess(freshData);
        }
        if (useCallback.current && afterInvalidationCallback.current) {
            afterInvalidationCallback.current(freshData);
            useCallback.current = false;
            afterInvalidationCallback.current = null;
        }

        if (options.persist) {
            if(globalCustomerId){
                saveToLocalStorage(freshData, queryId);
            }
        }
    };

    const data = useQuery(queryKey, getData, {
        ...options,
        placeholderData: placeholderData.current,
        onSuccess,
    });
    const save = () => {
        if (options.persist && data?.data) {
            saveToLocalStorage(data.data, queryId);
        }
    };

    // if there are other items in localStorage with the same name and a different customerId, delete them
    // to keep the localStorage clear
    useBeforeunload(() => clearOtherCustomersData(globalCustomerId));

    useEffect(() => {
        return save;
    }, []);

    const invalidateQuery = callBack => {
        if (callBack && typeof callBack === "function") {
            useCallback.current = true;
            afterInvalidationCallback.current = callBack;
        } else if (callBack) {
            console.error(
                "Non function provided to invalidateQuery. Make sure you provide a function or a falsy value, such as undefined, null, false or 0",
            );
        }
        showRefetch.current = true;
        queryClient.invalidateQueries(queryKey);
    };

    const updateQuery = callBackOrNewValue => {
        queryClient.setQueryData(queryKey, prev => {
            const updatedData =
                typeof callBackOrNewValue === "function"
                    ? callBackOrNewValue(prev)
                    : callBackOrNewValue;
            return updatedData;
        });
    };

    return {
        ...data,
        queryKey,
        invalidateQuery,
        data: data.data || options.defaultTo,
        updateQuery,
        isFetchingAfterCacheDataWasReturned:
            data.isFetching &&
            !placeholderData.current &&
            !data.isLoading &&
            showRefetch.current === true,
    };
};

export default customUseQuery;
```

Some things are specific to my project, like the customerId.
I'm using onBeforeUnload to delete data not belonging to the current customer, but this project specific.

You don't need to copy paste all this, but I believe it's very handy to have a custom hook around useQuery, so you can increase its potential and do things like running a callback with fresh data after the previous data has been invalidated or returning the invalidateQuery/updateQuery functions, so you don't need to use useQueryClient when you want to invalidate/update a query.